# Easy MVC question about the Magento controllers/observers methods

Tags: event-observer, model, mvc

I've created a Magento plugin with a simple admin html observer:

This file looks like this:

```
//File: /Model/Adminhtml/Observer.php

class Aaa_Bbb_Model_Adminhtml_Observer
{
        public function saveOrderData(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
        {
        // example
        $this->saveCustomOrderData();
        }

        public function saveCustomOrderData() {
           // save data to a custom database table. 
        }
}
```

Now I've to create an adminhtml controller in the file **/controllers/CustomOrderData.php**. In this file I have to call the method **saveCustomOrderData()** in my Observer.php.

How can I call this method? Or is there a better place to store data in a custom table, from 2 files (the observer and controller method)?

Answer (score 2):

In you case I recommend to create a **model**, that is responsible for data management and saving to the database.  Then call this model methods from the controller and observer when needed.

This is [official guide](https://wiki.magento.com/display/m1wiki/Create+a+custom+module+with+a+custom+database+table) for custom module with database table, where you can find how to create models, controllers and observers: